# how to check whether a column in mysql table is comma separated list of values of not

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

I have a column media_type with sample following values

```
*media_type*
-------------------
socialmedia, paper
tv
paper, tv
pamplet,board
tv,board,pamplet
```

I would want to filter my promotions which are being advertised through only one media.

Comment: using only mysql, you could use the `LOCATE()` function.

Comment: If it's a table in a relational database then there's nothing to worry about, because it couldn't possibly contain a delimited list. And if it contains a delimited list, then it couldn't possibly be a table in a relational database, so not our problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `locate()`:

```
select *
from mytable
where not locate(',', media_type)
```

This phrases as: get all rows whose `media_type` is not `null` and does not contain a comma.

A more portable approach uses `like`:

```
select *
from mytable
where media_type not like '%,%'
```